# SVN check-in code from a different user

Tags: svn

My predecessor left the company some days ago. Unfortunately he has forgotten to check-in all the changes he made to subversion. I can access his changes as the source code is on a common fileshare.  I want to check in his changes without losing it. What is the best way to approach?  The problem is that valid code is on the fileshare and not on subversion.

One way I can think of is to export the source code to a different place. Make “new” trunk and import all the code again.

Thank you for your suggestions in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd check in all code as yourself, and clearly stating in the commit message that these changes are actually from your predecessor. If there are any problems with the commit in the future, that way you can avoid being the guy/gal everyone is mad at :). Other than that, I do not see the need for a new `trunk` or anything.

Comment: Thank you Michael I have tried it, but does not work..... It will aks you to run a cleanUp, but even then I cannot check in

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand this part:

> The problem is that valid code is on the fileshare and not on subversion.

Do you mean, you can't just commit from the "fileshare"? Is fileshare a network share like `\\servername\share\some\path` ? If so, then if you install Git, it comes with a nice terminal app called Git Bash, in which you can do this:

```
cd //servername/share/some/path  # yes, forward slashes instead of \
svn commit                       # you must have `svn` on PATH, of course
```

If you don't want to install Git just for this (though I'm telling you it's worth it, it's a great terminal app), I suppose you could copy his entire work directory to another place where you can use your usual svn tools like TortoiseSVN or whatnot, and then update and commit.

In the worst case, if you don't have his `.svn` directories, just his updated files, then I think you would need to checkout `trunk` at the base revision that he used. If you don't know the exact revision then you can try to find out with `svn info -R \\servername\share\some\path` (take the latest), or else take a good guess. Checkout `trunk` at this old revision, copy his files on top, and then do `svn update`. You need to do this way rather than simply copying over the latest revision, because that will wipe out changes that others have committed since then. If you see what I mean.

I hope my previous proposals will work and you won't need to resort to the last one, because it can be hard to do right.

Comment: Thank you Janos, It is a network share .... I will try Git Bash....the idea to checkout trunk and to copy his file on top is a good idea... I will try few things after the weekend